# The focus order of input fields by pressing the Tab (ExtJS)

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, focus, tabbing

I have a 2 column fields in the form Sach by pressing "tab" focus moves to the next field in this column. And so I have to focus on the field passed to another column (left to right).

Use ExtJs 3.4

```
{
            xtype : 'fieldset',
            layout:'column',
            items : [
              {
                columnWidth:.5,
                layout: 'form',
                items:[
                  {
                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel  : 'ФИО',
                    name        : 'FIO_CONTACT',
                    validator   : validFio
                  },
                  {
                  fieldLabel  : 'Телефон',
                  name: 'PHONE_CONTACT',
                  plugins: [new Ext.ux.InputTextMask('+9(999)999-9999', false)]
                 }
                ]
              },
              {
                columnWidth:.5,
                layout: 'form',
                border         : false,
                items:[
                  {
                    fieldLabel  : 'E-mail',
                    name        : 'EMAIL_CONTACT',
                    vtype       : 'email',
                    vtypeText   : 'Некорректный email (пример myname@mail.ru)'
                  },
                  fax
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your input field's `tabindex="2"` attribute in the order as you want `tabindex="1"` will be focused first and so forth